# Dynamically changing schema of DB at runtime

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

We are onboarding Distributed tracing in our service. For that we want to add traceId column in Dynamo DBs for which streams are enabled. Other DBs which do not have DDB streams enabled should remain same as before.
In future we might also get a usecase wherein we need to switch on the DDB streams in an existing DDB and that would require adding traceId in that DB as well.

I wanted suggestions on a design that would ease switching between DDB schema with trace and without trace dynamically at runtime without requiring us to add/remove obj.setTrace(someTrace) statements every time we switch

I tried the [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNxBz.png)
but the problem is that DBOperations expects a generic class (Eg: method void save(T object)) and we cannot setTraceId() in a generic class

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.